# Double desktop problem in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, graphics

I am new to Ubuntu. I have created a Ubuntu Virtual Machine on one of the ESX server. When I started the Ubuntu it prompted me for update installation and then reboot. After reboot I see double desktop as shown [image: here]

I am doubtful about the update installation. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try a sudo unity --reset if you have admin priv then do without the sudo command this will attemp to reset unity and may help this particular problem try it see if it works will reset unity

Comment: `ERROR: The reset option is now deprecated` (Ubuntu 14 LTS)